# Rails app Stripe payment don't work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, key, stripe-payments

I implemented a Stripe payment system on a product selling Rails app; in development, everything works fine, even the webhook's to conclude the purchase.
But when after deployed to heroku, when i try to make the purchase process, it gets stuck after clicking the "Buy" button.... On Heroku logs it displays the following Fatal message:
" Stripe::AuthenticationError (No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = ". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface."
But everything was pushed and migrated.
Any hints?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you used a gem like "dotenv" for the API keys and other keys in development, you need to pass the keys to heroku like so:

```
heroku config:set STRIPE_KEY=abcdefg...
```